# SWRevealViewController how to remove swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using good control `SWRevealViewController`, but by some redone I want to track my own swipe gestures on my screen. So how can I switch off swipe options? I want to work only `revealToggle` method that attached to my button. Did someone faced with this? Thank you

Answer (score 17):

In order to disable the swipe gesture you can simple do:

```
self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer.enabled=NO;
```

For example:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer.enabled=NO;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer.enabled=YES;
}
```

Comment: self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer().isEnabled=false, worked for me in Swift 4.2

Answer (score 10):

In your viewDidLoad method,type the below code where you don't want to enable the swipe gesture:

```
SWRevealViewController *reveal = self.revealViewController;
reveal.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this method:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers) {
    [self removeGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

Comment: Where want to add this line?

Answer (score 1):

To stop the swipe in the SWRevealViewController:

In Swift 3.0

```
self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer().isEnabled = false
```